# 12.04 compiz closed error message

Tags: compiz

Win 7/12.04 dual boot system. Win 7 works fine, but 12.04 rarely boots normally- I have to use repair. After 12.04 does boot, cyclical system error message/report error message/administrator log on. I was able to get reason "compiz closed /usr/bin/compiz" and contact askubuntu.com. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This [sounds like a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score -1):

If you are faceing this problem then you should reinstall **compiz** in your machine. To do that open a terminal by pressing ***Ctrl+alt+t*** and type

```
sudo apt-get purge compiz*
```

Type

```
cd $HOME && rm -rf .compiz/ .config/compiz/
```

Type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:compiz/ppa && sudo apt-get update
```

Type

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install compiz
```

Type

```
sudo reboot
```

It will reinstall compiz.

Please check you have latest video driver installed in your system. or install it from

> System Settings> Additional driver

Comment: Remove Compiz you say?

Comment: I think my ans is wrong. Reinstalling compiz may solve this problem.

Comment: It probably is a bug in Compiz. Reinstalling won't really solve that issue. All you can do is to file a bug report and hope someone fixes the bug for you. On the other hand, removing Compiz will leave you with almost an unusable desktop.

Comment: Sorry for placing a wrong answer. :(